# How to pass parameters in Polymer 2.0 on-tap function?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm using Polymer 2.0 and I have a `dom-repeat` for different to-do cards. What I want to do is remove the card when I click on it.

So I tried this `on-tap=deleteNote([[index]])` which uses the index from the `dom-repeat`. However Polymer doesn't execute the function.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14):

Another solution could be the `dataset` object within the `event.target`. You can define your properties with the `data-` prefix:

```
<div on-tap="doSomething" data-item$="[[item]]"></div>
```

And within your `doSomething()` listener you can get the `dataset` object:

```
doSomething(event) {
  const item = event.target.dataset.item;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can access the model via the event argument's `model` property.

So you can access the index from `event.model.index`.

Comment: This is the appropriate solution.

Comment: @LeeGee Just noting that function arguments are called arguments in javascript (not parameters, even though parameters is still comprehensible) and that properties on an object are called properties (absolutely not fields).

Comment: @DavidMulder — jolly good, most correct. Javascript, JS, JavaScript even, but never 'javascript'. Do you have a link to the docs? That'd also help flesh out this excellent answer.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I am aware you can't. There are many discussions about that on the internet.

Of course, there is a way how to pass argument to function. You can save `[[index]]` in attribute of element and then get the attribute when needed.

Example:

```
<div on-tap='_deleteNote' indexed$='[[index]]'>
```

Then in script:

```
_deleteNote(e) {
  var index = e.target.getAttribute('indexed');
  ...
}
```

Once you get `index`, you can do whatever you want with it.

Don't forget to extend Polymer gestures if you are not using hybrid elements in Polymer 2.0.

```
class Foo extends Polymer.GestureEventListeners(Polymer.Element) {}
```

More about it: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/gesture-events#using-gesture-events

What is hybrid element: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/hybrid-elements

Answer (score -2):

`on-tap` does not appear to be implemented in Polymer 2.0. If you instead use `on-click` then it will work.

EDIT: see below comment.

Comment: There is on-tap. You have to extend Polymer gestureEventListeners.  `class Foo extends Polymer.GestureEventListeners(Polymer.Element) {}`

Comment: @KubaŠimonovský `click` is [now recommended](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/gesture-events) for mobile over `tap`.

Comment: @brandaemon yep, That's right. People should use `on-click`