# How to pass argument in on-click function in a polymer dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, polymer-2.x

here is the code sample:

```html
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{tableData}}" as="data">
    <tr>
        <td class="link" on-click="_test">{{data.id_Mission}}</td>
        <td>{{data.nom}}</td>
        <td>{{data.resume}}</td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

And I would like to pass an argument to the `_test` function. 
Like this `on-click="_test({{data.id_Mission}})"`.
Is there a way to perform that ?

Have a nice day :)

Comment: Doesn't `_test(data.id_Mission)` work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters in Polymer 2.0 on-tap function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43505067/how-to-pass-parameters-in-polymer-2-0-on-tap-function)

Comment: Thank you the answer was here effectively.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround here it is, but i'm still interested if there is a solution like the one I was asking for.

```js
//Build the table
 _buildTable(data)
{
    this.$.spinner.style.display = 'none';
    this.tableHead = Object.keys(data[0]);
    this.tableData = data;
    setTimeout(() => {//After the data is rendered launch a function
        this._test();
    });
}
//Bind event to each element
_test()
{
    var links = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll(".link");
    console.log(links);
    links.forEach(link => {
        link.addEventListener('click', function(){
            console.log("Click !", link.innerText);// the innerText contain the data I want
        });
    });
}
```

```html
<!-- The table -->
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Mission</th>
        <th>Nom</th>
        <th>Résumé</th>
        <!--<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{tableHead}}" as="thead">
            <th>{{thead}}</th>
        </template>-->
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{tableData}}" as="data">
            <tr>
                <td class="link">{{data.id_Mission}}</td>
                <td>{{data.nom}}</td>
                <td>{{data.resume}}</td>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </tbody>
</table>
```